# postGIS in Linux: dbf file can not be opened

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, postgis

Downloaded file is unzipped. I moved it up the folder tree. I have the very latest version of LibreOffice in my Ubuntu. But I can't migrate the data therein to my postgis database. Have been working on this for some time any pointers appreciated. Linux output is below.

```
shp2pgsql -c -D -I tl_2019_us_cd116.shp gis.congress | psql -U sporter tutorial
```

> Unable to open tl_2019_us_cd116.shp or tl_2019_us_cd116.SHP
> tl_2019_us_cd116: dbf file (.dbf) can not be opened.

Per recommendations below I've been working on permissions but am stuck again. I'm logged in as root user on the path that has access to the file and as seen below it states ownership is being changed. But ls -l shows the original owner

```
root@DESKTOP-VDI7BFT:/mnt/c/Users/sport# chown -v sporter tl_2019_us_cd116
```

> changed ownership of 'tl_2019_us_cd116' from sporter399 to sporter

But I don't think the ownership really changes:

```
ls -l tl_2019_us_cd116
```

> -rwxrwxrwx 1 sporter399 sporter399 (7 times over for each file within the folder, all showing sporter399 which is what I'm trying to change)

Comment: What di you get for `ls -l tl_2019_us_cd116.shp`?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Did you take a look at the file permissions?

Comment: So now the issue, as stated above, is being stuck on file ownership. The permissions look good, I think. Why I'm getting the explicit statement that ownership is changed but nothing changes at the ls -l is mysterious, And the file still can't be opened.